# T-SQL Multiple counts for member types over time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm Looking for a way in T-SQL to get counts of members of different types over period of months and years. My Table:

```
+-------------+-----------+------------
| Member_type | Join_date |  End_date  |
+-------------+-----------+------------+
| TYPE1       | 12-Nov-07 | 12/11/2015 |
| TYPE2       | 24-Nov-10 | 07/07/2016 |
| TYPE3       | 29-Apr-08 | 28/04/2009 |
| TYPE2       | 28-Apr-06 | 31/03/2007 |
| TYPE1       | 11-Jul-06 | 30/06/2007 |
| TYPE2       | 13-Mar-08 | 12/06/2011 |
+-------------+-----------+------------+
```

I'm looking for results like this

```
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Member_type | Jan-15 | Feb-15 | Mar-15 | Apr-15 |
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| TYPE1       |      1 |      5 |      4 |      2 |
| TYPE2       |      6 |      4 |      2 |      1 |
| TYPE3       |      5 |      6 |      7 |      8 |
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

that shows total amount of members of given type during Jan, Feb etc, for recent years.
(those that joined - those that left)

So far I got to this

```
SELECT COUNT("membership_type") AS JANUARY2015 
FROM "dbo"."Data" T0 
WHERE (join_date < DATEADD(month, -2, GETDATE())) 
  AND (join_date > GETDATE()) 
GROUP BY T0."membership_type" ;
```

Comment: also why are the join date and the end date showing different formats

Comment: Sorry about different format of date that happen when I tried to copy some that through excel

Comment: edit the question to add your attempt, properly formatted please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Member_type
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(join_date) = 2015 AND MONTH(join_date) = 1 THEN 1 END) AS [Jan-15]
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(join_date) = 2015 AND MONTH(join_date) = 2 THEN 1 END) AS [Feb-15]
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(join_date) = 2015 AND MONTH(join_date) = 3 THEN 1 END) AS [Mar-15]
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(join_date) = 2015 AND MONTH(join_date) = 4 THEN 1 END) AS [Apr-15]
    ...
FROM MarketingData
GROUP BY Member_type
```